# iOS - How to type in a decimal number in textbox without first entering a 0 first?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm finishing up a simple iOS8 app written in SWIFT which involves numbers being entered in at times. Sometimes the numbers need to be decimals and I noticed that unless I enter a 0 first before the decimal point, the decimal button won't work and nothing will be inputted into the text box.

I was thinking about just making the textbox start with 0, that way the user can just start typing in a decimal without have to enter in 0 by themselves first. I'm hoping there is a simple function that I can just use to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Describe how the text field is configured. How are you forcing the text field to accept only numbers? Are you using a delegate? If so, show us the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try to explain as well as I can. Each of my UITextFields are IBOutlets in my ViewController. So the IBOutlets in my code is called firstTextLabel, secondTextLabel, and so forth. I then have an "if statement" where I do the following. if let firstVal = self.firstTextLabel.text?.toDouble(){//conversion formula goes here}else{firstTextLabel.text ="" secondTextLabel.text=""}}. For the toDouble() function I used the following code. extension String
{
  func toDouble() -> Double?
  {
    return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
  }
}

Comment: Don't paste code into a comment. Edit your question and paste the code there. Make sure you indent each line of code by an extra four spaces so the web site will format it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Following works:

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        let fmt = NSNumberFormatter()
        return fmt.numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    } 
}
```

and then in your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func convert(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let d = textField.text.toDouble() {
        println("Got a double \(d)")
    } else {
        println("Not a double \(textField.text)")
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you, post more code, the problem is elsewhere.